# How to batch remove passwords from word documents (when I know the password)

Tags: macos, ms-word, passwords, applescript

I have inherited several thousand word documents in the older .doc and .docx formats. They are all 'secured' / locked with the same password. I have that password. I would like to remove the password lock once and for all.

Is there a way to do this using Applescript? I know it's possible for PDFs, but is Microsoft Word (or doing it through Pages?) scriptable in that way? Are there any system tools or would Automator be the way? I'd like the word files just to be permanently unlocked (i.e. the password access restriction removed), or perhaps just a PDF of the file to be generated?

UPDATE: one reply put me onto the MSWord script library, which seems to have an option for decrypting. This is the code that I assembled together from other sources. Any ideas for actually making it work? It gives me an error message currently.

```js
set this_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Pick the folder containing the files to process:") as string
tell application "System Events"
 set these_files to every file of folder this_folder
end tell
repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_files
 set this_file to (item i of these_files as alias)
 set this_info to info for this_file
 if visible of this_info is true and alias of this_info is false then
  tell application "Microsoft Word"
   activate
   open this_file
   unprotect this_file password "samplepassword"
  end tell
 end if
end repeat
```

Comment: You can do it easily in Applescript, using a loop through al documents and for each, open the document and use "unprotect password "xxx". Check Word Applescript dictionary

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes to my query following your suggestion.